# Clicking "clear site data" in Chrome Dev tools, on an unrelated website, logs me out of chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Steps to reproduce:

- Open any website (even localhost)
- Open dev tools for that website
- Open the "Application" tab
- Click "Clear site data"
- Now on top right says "Paused" and asks you to sign again in chrome

I do not expect to be logged out of my Gmail, Calendar, etc. just from clearing site data on a website that is not a google site.

I tried to get help from official google forum, but they just closed my question. Can I have any help here?

Comment: also found here https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/17942706?hl=en